# Create aggregate columns based on list of headers

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, aggregate

I have a dataframe with survey data. It contains several other columns with demographic data (eg age, department etc) and the columns with ratings. Would like to add some columns to the dataframe based on calculations of the ratings columns.

The purpose of adding the columns is to provide a) get a count of Favourable responses b) get the percentage of Favourable responses (no of favourable responses / no of items in that factor) c) get the factor level percentage of Favourable responses (where it will be NaN if there are any items with NaN that belong to the factor)
The table below shows an example of how it will be applied to the Coaching Factor
Would like to replicate this for the other Factors like Diversity, Leadership, Engagement.

```
Coach_q1  Coach_q2      Coach_q8    coach_favcount   coach_fav_perc   coach_agg_perc
Favourable   Neutral    Favourable   2                  66.6%          66.6%
Favourable   Favourable NaN          2                  100%           NaN
Favourable   Favourable Unfavourable 2                  66.6%          66.6%  
NaN          NaN        Unfavourable 0                  0%             NaN
```

I've used the following  code and it works, however, am only able to get the fav_count column and the fav_perc column for Coaching. Would like a) get the _agg_perc column and b) apply this to all other Factors.

```
#Get the Coaching Columns
coaching_agg = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Coaching_')] 

#Create a column to store the number of favourable responses
df['coaching_fav_count'] = df[coaching_cols == 'Favourable'].notna().sum(axis=1)

#create a column to store the percentage of favourable responses
df['coaching_fav_perc'] = df['coaching_fav'] / len(coaching_agg.columns)
```

Im guessing the logic behind the for loop would be to a) create a list of the rating columns (see code below) and b) create a function to calculate the counts, percentages of favourable responses, look for presence of NaN at the item level and c) create a for loop to apply the function to the rating columns.

```
#Create a list made up of rating cols
ratingcollist = ['Coaching_','Communication_','Development_','Diversity_','Engagement_']

ratingcols = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(ratingcollist))]
```

Appreciate any form of help that i can get, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by recoding the NaN values in the columns to 'Missing' and applying the mask recommended by @jezrael

```
#create a list of all the rating columns
ratingcollist = ['Coaching_','Diversity', 'Leadership', 'Engagement']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list keyword
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns
    mask = (df[cols] != 'Missing').all(axis=1)
    
#create 3 new columns for each factor, one for count of Favourable responses, one for percentage of Favourable responses, and one for Factor Level percentage of Favourable responses

    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / df[cols].count(axis=1)
        df.loc[mask,f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need processing each value of list separately:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Coach_q1': ['Favourable', 'Favourable', 'Favourable', 'nan'], 
                   'Coach_q2': ['Neutral', 'Favourable', 'Favourable', 'NaN'], 
                   'Coach_q8': ['Favourable', 'nan', 'Unfavourable', 'Unfavourable']})
    
print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable
1  Favourable  Favourable           nan
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable
3         nan         NaN  Unfavourable

#replace nan and NaN strings to missing values
df = df.replace(['nan','NaN'], np.nan)

ratingcollist = ['Coach_','Communication_','Development_','Diversity_','Engagement_']

for rat in ratingcollist:
    #filter columns by substrings
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns

    #mask for no missing values
    mask = df[cols].notna().all(axis=1)
    
    #create new columns if match
    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / df[cols].count(axis=1)
        df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)
```

---

```
print (df)

     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8  coach_fav_count  coach_fav_perc  \
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable                2        0.666667   
1  Favourable  Favourable           NaN                2        1.000000   
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable                2        0.666667   
3         NaN         NaN  Unfavourable                0        0.000000   

   coach_agg_perc  
0        0.666667  
1             NaN  
2        0.666667  
3             NaN
```

---

If replace `nan`s to word missing output for `fav_perc` is wrong, second value should by `1`, because count exclude misisng values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Coach_q1': ['Favourable', 'Favourable', 'Favourable', 'nan'], 
                   'Coach_q2': ['Neutral', 'Favourable', 'Favourable', 'NaN'], 
                   'Coach_q8': ['Favourable', 'nan', 'Unfavourable', 'Unfavourable']})
    
print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable
1  Favourable  Favourable           nan
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable
3         nan         NaN  Unfavourable

df = df.replace(['nan','NaN'], 'Missing')
print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable
1  Favourable  Favourable       Missing
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable
3     Missing     Missing  Unfavourable
```

---

```
#create a list of all the rating columns
ratingcollist = ['Coach_','Diversity', 'Leadership', 'Engagement']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list keyword
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns
    mask = (df[cols] != 'Missing').all(axis=1)
    
#create 3 new columns for each factor, one for count of Favourable responses, 
#one for percentage of Favourable responses, and one for Factor Level percentage of Favourable responses

    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / df[cols].count(axis=1)
        df.loc[mask,f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)
```

---

```
print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8  coach_fav_count  coach_fav_perc  \
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable                2        0.666667   
1  Favourable  Favourable       Missing                2        0.666667   
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable                2        0.666667   
3     Missing     Missing  Unfavourable                0        0.000000   

   coach_agg_perc  
0        0.666667  
1             NaN  
2        0.666667  
3             NaN
```

So if want use `Missing` is necessary change `count` to `sum` with compare not equal `Missing`:

```
#create a list of all the rating columns
ratingcollist = ['Coach_','Diversity', 'Leadership', 'Engagement']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list keyword
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns
    mask = (df[cols] != 'Missing').all(axis=1)
    
#create 3 new columns for each factor, one for count of Favourable responses, 
#one for percentage of Favourable responses, and one for Factor Level percentage of Favourable responses

    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / df[cols].ne('Missing').sum(axis=1)
        df.loc[mask,f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)
```

---

```
print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2      Coach_q8  coach_fav_count  coach_fav_perc  \
0  Favourable     Neutral    Favourable                2        0.666667   
1  Favourable  Favourable       Missing                2        1.000000   
2  Favourable  Favourable  Unfavourable                2        0.666667   
3     Missing     Missing  Unfavourable                0        0.000000   

   coach_agg_perc  
0        0.666667  
1             NaN  
2        0.666667  
3             NaN
```

Comment: without complications :)

Comment: In my opinion It's simple and intuitive, so upvoted

Comment: @jezrael if i'd like to create aggregate columns with the suffix _agg_perc where it calculates the percentage of favourable responses only if there are no missing values (e.g., the percentage of the agg_perc column will be zero for both factors in row 2), how should i go about doing it?

Comment: @jezrael yup done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774661/using-a-for-loop-to-create-additional-columns-that-calculate-percentages-based-o

Comment: @jezrael can't seem to work, the agg_perc columns are of similar value to the fav_per columns

Comment: @jezrael with real data

Comment: @jezrael unfortunately yes.

Comment: @jezrael all the dtypes of the rating columns are object. There is are 2 issues though, when i print (cols), only the Engagement cols are printed. Is there something wrong with 'cols = rawdf7.filter(like=rat).columns'. Also, when i print 'mask.unique', the values are all true which means the mask working on all values.

Comment: @jezrael it gives me all of the columns including my demographics

Comment: @jezrael i think i found the issue. When i call df['Coach_q1'].isnull().sum(), there are no null values. Meaning the NaNs are not detected. That is why the mask is not working

Comment: @wjie08 - So need `df = df.replace(['nan','NaN'], np.nan)` before my solution. It is wrong for me data are confidental, so cannot find this problem. Btw, convert to `NaN`s is necessary, else `count` working wrong.

Comment: @wjie08 - Answer was edited for correct working with `NaN`s and also with `Missing`.

Answer (score 2):

We can try without loops:

```
columns_split = df.columns.str.split('_')
count = (df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, columns_split)), axis=1)
           .stack()
           .eq('Favourable')
           .sum(level=0))

s = columns_split.str[0].to_series().add('_%Fav')

new_df = (df.join(count.add_suffix('_FavCount'))
           .join(count.add_suffix('_%Fav').div(s.value_counts()))
         )

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Coaching_q1 Coaching_q2 Diversity_q1 Diversity_q2  Coaching_FavCount  \
0  Favourable     Neutral   Favourable   Favourable                1.0   
1  Favourable  Favourable   Favourable    Favourble                2.0   
2         NaN  Favourable          NaN          NaN                1.0   

   Diversity_FavCount  Coaching_%Fav  Diversity_%Fav  
0                 2.0            0.5             1.0  
1                 1.0            1.0             0.5  
2                 0.0            0.5             0.0
```

Comment: can't seem to get a result. ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names