# Using a for loop to create additional columns that calculate percentages based on multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with survey data. The survey data assesses multiple factors like coaching, diversity, engagement etc. There are also several other columns which capture demographic data (e.g., age, department etc). I would like to add columns based on the columns that contain the ratings.

The purpose of adding the columns is to a) provide a count of Favourable responses, b) to get the percentage of Favourable responses (no of favourable responses / no of items in that factor) and c) to get the percentage of Favourable responses at the Factor level (with the condition that if there are missing reponses for any item, it would be NULL at the Factor level)

The table below shows the desired output where only Coaching items are factor are included. The table should contain other rating columns and should apply for Factors like Diversity, Leadership, Engagement etc.

```
Coach_q1     Coach_q2    Coach_q3      coach_fav_count  coach_fav_perc  coach_agg_perc 
Favourable   Neutral     Favourable    2                66%            66%        
Favourable   Favourable  Fabourable    3                100%           100%
NaN          Favourable  NaN           1                33%            NaN
Favourable   NaN         Favourable    2                66%            NaN
```

The following code works in getting the _favcount columns and the _fav% columns. The ratingcollist is used to only apply the transformations on columns with those prefixes. However, am unable to get the factor level column which aims to get the percentage of favourable responses for the entire factor - ONLY if all questions were answered for that particular factor (i.e., if there were missing responses in any of the items within a particular factor, then the factor would yield a NaN value).

Appreciate any form of help i can get, thank you.

```
ratingcollist = ['Coach_','Diversity_','Leadership_','Engagement_']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list keyword
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns

#create 2 new columns for each factor, one for count of Favourable responses and one for percentage of Favourable responses
    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = (df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add mask for test if all values are not missing by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and only for this add percentage column in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Coach_q1': ['Favourable', 'Favourable', np.nan, 'Favourable'], 'Coach_q2': ['Neutral', 'Favourable', 'Favourable', np.nan], 'Coach_q3': ['Favourable', 'Favourable', np.nan, 'Favourable']})
```

---

```
ratingcollist = ['Coach_','Diversity_','Leadership_','Engagement_']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list keyword
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns
    
    mask = df[cols].notna().all(axis=1)

#create 2 new columns for each factor, one for count 
#of Favourable responses and one for percentage of Favourable responses
    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] = (df[cols] == 'Favourable').sum(axis=1)
        df[f'{rat.lower()}fav_perc'] = (df.loc[mask, f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)) * 100

print (df)
     Coach_q1    Coach_q2    Coach_q3  coach_fav_count  coach_fav_perc
0  Favourable     Neutral  Favourable                2       66.666667
1  Favourable  Favourable  Favourable                3      100.000000
2         NaN  Favourable         NaN                1             NaN
3  Favourable         NaN  Favourable                2             NaN
```

Comment: hi @jezrael the transformation cant seem to work. Am getting similar values to the fav_perc columns

Comment: @wjie08 - It is weird, in sample data working well.

Comment: I can't seem to locate the code that creates the _factor_agg% columns, is there something I am missing?

Comment: @wjie08 - I think it is `coaching_fav_perc` and `diversity_fav_perc` columns

Comment: i see, but the codes don't seem to create the coaching_factor_agg% column

I used this the following code but does not work: 

 df[f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = (df.loc[mask,f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)) * 100

Comment: @wjie08 - yes, it is weird, for me working correct - last values are NaNs, because for both `coaching` and `diversity` are missing values.

Comment: when i use this code:  df[f'{rat.lower()}agg_perc'] = (df.loc[mask,f'{rat.lower()}fav_count'] / len(cols)) * 100

all of the columns for fav_count, fav_perc and agg_perc become NaN

Comment: @wjie08 - It is weird, added sample data from question and for me it working perfectly.